# Where live struct with reference type as a property

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, struct

I've created struct with static array of reference type and property which take object from that array by unique id stored in struct - but i don't know it make any sense, i want to store struct on the stack.

```
struct TestStruct
{
 static TestClass[] Instances = new TestClass[16]; 
 int uid; //max value = 15
 TestClass Instance
 {
  get { return Instances[uid]; }
 } 
}
```

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea....

Comment: It would really help if you could *show* your struct instead of *describing* it.

Comment: You can never actually "have" a reference type object to begin with. All you can ever have is a reference *to* a reference type (which lives somewhere on the heap). Your reference is actually a value type, which implicitly dereferences back to the heap object when you access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so `Instances` is a static variable - so that will be on the heap. Likewise the array itself is a reference type, so that's going to be on the heap.

Only the `uid` variable is actually part of the value for a particular TestStruct, and that will be on the heap or on the stack depending on the context.

[It's all an implementation detail though](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx)... what are you really trying to *achieve*?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid Garbage Collection, with ANTS profiler i get to the objects which causes GC - it is mostly two types of object. Author create them as a class which is not necessary IMHO.

Comment: @nilphilus: Given that your struct only contains a single int, why not just use an int to start with? Whether a *static* variable is in a struct or a class makes no difference. Have you actually found that this GC is causing a genuine performance problem?

Comment: whole struct is much bigger, this is 'TestStruct'.  GC is called each 30s - sometimes less sometimes more.

Comment: @nilphilus: Okay, so you've given us something which doesn't represent what you're trying to do. That's not terribly useful for trying to help you.

Comment: @Jon whole struct has a 250+ lines of code and comments - inside struct i have int, float, enum and one delegate values.

Comment: @nilphilus: It doesn't *sound* like an ideal candidate to be a struct, to be honest. What level of GC is occurring every 30s, and how long is it taking? How many instances of this type are you creating?

Comment: GC is pretty fast, but short freeze could be spotted. I don't remember how many instances is creating - but between memory snapshot i getting around +800kB of memory for that type (1MB and GC start collecting thrash)  - Why it shouldn't be a struct?

Comment: @nilphilus: Is it naturally a single logical value? If it contains an `int`, a `float`, an `enum` and a delegate it doesn't *sound* like it's naturally a value type.

Comment: @nilphilus: It's still not clear that you've *got* a "problem with GC". One GC every 30 seconds doesn't immediately sound like a significant problem. You need to find out what the *real* hit of this is - how much of your CPU time is being spent in the GC?

Comment: this wp7 game project so actually GC is a problem (profiling was made on windows version) - no one like short freezes during gameplay.

Comment: @nilphilus: Okay, it would have been handy to say that to start with... it's not entirely unusual to bend designs out of shape for performance in mobile apps. On the other hand, I would really try to measure the difference in performance before committing to that.

Comment: Sorry for that, i'm more concentrated on problem which is really hard when i'm sick of it xD    I've checked that and get 35s - which is not a profit when i look on bugs created while changing class to struct...

Comment: @nilphilus: Yup, that's the cost of bending a design. Performance is hard :(

Answer (score 5):

The struct itself will be stored on the stack.

TestClass is your Reference Type. No matter what you do, those are going to be stored on the heap. In this case `Instances` is a static array on the heap.

Comment: The struct shown doesn't contain any references on a per-value basis. The only reference is in a static variable.

Comment: @Jon - The example wasn't there when I originally posted my answer and this is the first I've been back to update.

Comment: True, although the "static array" part was - which was why I originally asked for more details :)

Comment: @Jon - In my defense, it's early in the morning and I had a hard time deciphering the original question to begin with. :P

Comment: Absolutely fair enough - it wasn't at all clear, and it's still not *that* clear IMO...